# Dynamic SPARQL endpoint in the function of the HDT file

Tags: sparql, rdf, endpoint

Is there some web interface or service in which, for a given a link to one or many HDT files, and a SPARQL query returns the results from the query.

A kind of dynamic SPARQL endpoint in the function of the HDT file.

In other words:

Input: Link to the HDT file(s)(1...*) and SPARQL query.
Output: results from the query.

**Example**:

Input: `http://lod-a-lot.lod.labs.vu.nl/data/LOD_a_lot_v1.hdt, "Select * Where {?s ?p ?o} limit 10"`

Output: `Results from the query.`

It should be on the web (website/Webservice).

It looks trivial, but I would like to confirm before starting to implement it.

Comment: Trivial, available as an existing web service, probably not.  Consider the potential for DOS attacks, HDT files are extremely compressed and can contain vast amounts of data.  You'd be asking someone to allow uploading large and arbitrary data files and then process a potentially expensive query over them.  Perfectly possible as a web service but you'll want to consider security, data/request throttling etc

Comment: And you probably need to worry about data caching as otherwise loading the data files on each request could become very expensive (in time, bandwidth consumption and performance)